# How to compare dates from the database with the dates in the calendar twig?

Tags: php, symfony, date, twig

I would like compare the dates in the database with the dates on the calendar.

In my controller I get all dates:

```
$employments = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Bundle:Employment')
            ->findActualEmployments();

$freedays = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Bundle:FreeDays')
            ->findBy(array(), array('date'=>'asc' )  );
foreach($freedays as $free){
     $list_freedays[] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($free->getDate()->format('Y-m-d')));
        }
$days = array();
    foreach($freedays as $free){
    for($i=1;$i<=$maxDay;$i++)
    {
        $days[$i] = array(
          "date" => date('Y-m-d',strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$i)), 
          "name_en" => date('D',strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$i)),
          "name_trans" => 'main.'.strtolower(date('D',strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$i))),
          "free_day" => $list_freedays
        );}}
return $this->render('Bundle:Holiday:index.html.twig',array(
        'employments'=>$employments,
        'days' => $days,
        'list_freedays' => $list_freedays,
        'form' => $form->createView()
         ));
```

In My Twig I try to compare dates like below:

```
<tbody>
            <tr>
                <th id="col2" align="center">
                    {% set time = "now"|date("U","Europe/Warsaw") %}

                    {{['main',date('2015-' ~ j ~ '-01') |date('F')|lower]|join('.')|trans({},'Bundle')}}
                </th>

        {% for number,day in days %}

                        {#mark weekend#}
                        {% if  day.name_trans   == 'SAT'  %}    

                            <th align="center" id="col4" > 

                        {%elseif day.name_trans  == 'SUN'%}
                            <th align="center" id="col4" >

                        {%elseif (day.date) == (day.free_day[3])%}
                            {{day.free_day[3]}}  
                            <th align="center" id="col4" >
                        {%else%} 
                            <th align="center" id="col3" >                                            
                        {% endif  %}      
                                 {# day content here #} 
                      {% if numday in range(1,daysInMonth) %}   
                              {{ numday }}
                              {%set numday = numday + 1 %}  

                              {{ day.name_trans }}</th>   

                       {%endif%}    
                      {%endfor%}

            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Everything works well if in this line "{%elseif (day.date) == (day.free_day[3])%}" I put an numbers from 0 to 3 because I have four dates in array. How compare to all of the dates of the array, not just one. When I change this line to "{%elseif (day.date) == (day.free_day)%}" then I got error "Notice: Array to string conversion in..." 
Please help.

Comment: It looks like you just need to loop through your array of dates, checking each one.

Comment: @River ok, but where and how? any example? I try nested loop like {%elseif (day.date) in range (day.free_day[0],day.free_day[3])%}  but it doesnt work. Any idea?

Comment: Turns out there's a nice method for this. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that was very simple. I change this line :

```
{%elseif (day.date) == (day.free_day[3])%}
```

to this:

```
{%elseif (day.date) in (day.free_day)%}
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

You might try the [in_array method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
//True if day.date is in day.free_day
{%elseif (in_array (day.date , day.free_day))%}
```

There is also an optional boolean parameter `strict` that you can set to true if you wish. This makes the checking of item in array match types as well.

Comment: But function "in_array" does not exist in twig template.

Comment: @Lukas ah, apologies. I'm unfamiliar with twig (and php in general). Seems like you found the twig equivalent on your own though.